# How to fix snapd darktable with photos on NFS mount access denied?

Tags: permissions, snap

I have all my photos on a separate (local) NFS server which is mounted at `/home/majira_home`. I have been using this setup for years with darktable. But after I installed darktable from snap (`sudo snap install darktable`), darktable is unable to open the mount, giving this error:

> #### Could not read the contents of majira_home
>
> Error opening directory '/home/majira_home': Permission denied

[Transcribed from [this screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2vYY.png).]

Yet, this is something I've always been able to do
from the lighttable → images → add to library.

Strangely, if I double-click the filename directory from a file browser opened into the mounted volume, darktable is able to both open the file and export images to that directory.

My question is: what changes can/should I make to any snap/darktable profile, or AppArmor config/profiles to get this working? 
I've already spent 10+ hours trying to figure this out.

I've added permissions in `/etc/fstab` at mount
to give the mount point my UID and GID.

```
$ ls -l /home/majira_home/
drwxrwxrwx 100 daudi daudi 4096 Apr 25  2021 daudi


System information:
System:    Host: wstn Kernel: 5.4.0-132-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.5.0 
           Desktop: Xfce 4.14.1 tk: Gtk 3.22.30 wm: xfwm4 dm: LightDM 
           Distro: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 


    darktable                4.0.1                       89     latest/stable  sergiusens    -
        
    $ snap connections darktable
        Interface                 Plug                                Slot                              Notes
        content[gnome-42-2204]    darktable:gnome-42-2204             gnome-42-2204:gnome-42-2204       -
        content[gtk-3-themes]     darktable:gtk-3-themes              gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes    -
        content[icon-themes]      darktable:icon-themes               gtk-common-themes:icon-themes     -
        content[sound-themes]     darktable:sound-themes              gtk-common-themes:sound-themes    -
        dbus                      -                                   darktable:session-dbus-interface  -
        desktop                   darktable:desktop                   :desktop                          -
        desktop-legacy            darktable:desktop-legacy            :desktop-legacy                   -
        gsettings                 darktable:gsettings                 :gsettings                        -
        home                      darktable:home                      :home                             -
        network                   darktable:network                   :network                          -
        network-bind              darktable:network-bind              :network-bind                     -
        opengl                    darktable:opengl                    :opengl                           -
        password-manager-service  darktable:password-manager-service  -                                 -
        removable-media           darktable:removable-media           :removable-media                  -
        wayland                   darktable:wayland                   :wayland                          -
        x11                       darktable:x11                       :x11                              -

Nov 21 12:37:09 jabari audit[5411]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.darktable.darktable" name="/etc/fstab" pid=5411 comm="darktable" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov 21 12:37:09 jabari audit[5411]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.darktable.darktable" name="/proc/5411/mountinfo" pid=5411 comm="darktable" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Nov 21 12:37:09 jabari audit[5411]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.darktable.darktable" name="/proc/5411/mounts" pid=5411 comm="darktable" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Nov 21 12:37:09 jabari kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1669063029.067:132): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.darktable.darktable" name="/etc/fstab" pid=5411 comm="darktable" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov 21 12:37:09 jabari kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1669063029.067:133): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.darktable.darktable" name="/proc/5411/mountinfo" pid=5411 comm="darktable" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Nov 21 12:37:09 jabari kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1669063029.067:134): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.darktable.darktable" name="/proc/5411/mounts" pid=5411 comm="darktable" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Nov 21 12:37:09 jabari kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1669063029.071:135): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.darktable.darktable" name="/home/majira_home/" pid=5411 comm="darktable" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov 21 12:37:09 jabari audit[5411]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.darktable.darktable" name="/home/majira_home/" pid=5411 comm="darktable" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov 21 12:37:09 jabari audit[5411]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.darktable.darktable" name="/home/majira_home/" pid=5411 comm="darktable" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

Comment: work-around found: $ ln -s <target-directory-on nfs> <~/Pictures/<anyname>, then darktable is able to open this and access the RAW files for processing.

Comment: that's not completely correct. "removable-media           darktable:removable-media" settings in snap are there to access other media. I think there is something restrictive in how darktable snap package has been built. Additionally, the snap sandboxing is not to explain. I think there's something in the appamor profile that is restricting the access from initially opening the NFS. but doesn't restrict the access otherwise.

Comment: snaps are a real pain, they often have missing features. The ubuntu darktable has no opencl or print module. Use the opensuse build service repository as indicated on the darktable website.

Comment: Snaps are a massive pain and to be avoided if at all possible (I would say "for all but the most trivial tasks" but it's often the trivial stuff where they fail the hardest - like working in /tmp). Unfortunately it's not always easy to avoid them.  I also suggest asking on Unix and Linux in this specific case, but generally it's not worth fighting with them.  A mod may be able to migrate

Answer (score 0):

Big thank you for the comments on this thread, I would never had realised the problem is related to the fact I've installed a snap package.

For others who might come across this.

1. `sudo snap remove darktable`
2. Debian based users use this link for adding the ppa or just downloading the package manually : https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=graphics:darktable&package=darktable
3. followed by the usual `sudo update && sudo apt install darktable`

> Note: This will install the latest version which isn't available on Ubuntu standard repositories. It will install a lot of extra dependencies.

If you already have a database built up in Darktable (even if it is empty), upon your first launch you'll be prompted to update your databases/library. Do so, be patient as it seems to look like nothing is happening. Took about 20 seconds on my empty library, during which I thought it crashed and tried reloading.